# How to get timeout or delay working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a complete noob when it comes to AngularJS. I need some help getting a message to show for a period of time and then go away.

The following code writes a judge's score to a database and then prevents that judge from scoring again until the score has been cleared from the database. I want a message to appear below the judge panel when the judge submits their score, something like "OK!". Currently, it shows up when isLoading = true is set but only very briefly because as you can see from the code below it gets turned to false. I need it to turn to false automatically, but only after 3 or so seconds.

```
async send(): Promise<any> {
try {
  this.isLoading = true;
  const star: { isValid: boolean } = await this.judgeService.submitScoreIsValid(this.id).toPromise();
  if (star.isValid === true) {
    await this.judgeService.write(this.id, {score: this.currentScore}).toPromise();
    this.status = true;
  } else {
    this.status = false;
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
} finally {
  this.isLoading = false;
}
}
```

I want the isLoading to equal true but only for about 3 seconds. How can I do this?

I've tried going:

```
this.isLoading=true;    
$timeout(function(){ this.isLoading=false; }, 3000);
```

but it didn't work, it just stays up and doesn't go away after 3sec. Can anyone help?

My frontend is this:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading">
     <h5>OK!</h5>
</div>
```

*edited to reflect changes made by the suggestion of one of the answers below.

Comment: Are you using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org) or [Angular](https://angular.io)? Please note that both frameworks are _completely different_ from each other.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have the choice and aren't stuck with updating legacy code, life will be much easier if you work with the new Angular, instead of the old AngularJS. You won't have to worry so much about the [digest cycle](https://www.dotsquares.com/news_events/what-is-digest-cycle-in-angular-js-and-how-does-it-make-two-way-data-binding-possible/), and whether or not changes you make to the values of variables are detected by AngularJS.

At any rate, the code you've written tells angular to set `isLoading` to `true` *after* 3 seconds, not *for* 3 seconds. What you need to do is:

```
$timeout(function() { this.isLoading = true; });
$timeout(function() { this.isLoading = false; }, 3000);
```

...that is, first set it to `true`, then after 3 seconds, set it to `false`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've made the changes to the code but the message shows up but stays there forever. it won't go away.

Comment: I updated the code above. I didn't notice that you weren't in a proper digest context before doing the timeout as well. Hopefully this works. (It's been a long time since I touched AngularJS!)

Comment: same problem. the "OK!" doesn't disappear. it remains up.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this:

```
$timeout(() => this.isLoading = false, 3000);
```

non arrow functions create a new `this` context, arrow functions will preserve the outer `this`

Comment: thanks, but "OK!" doesn't go away. it remains up.


`async send(): Promise<any> {
try {
  this.isLoading = true;
  const star: { isValid: boolean } = await this.judgeService.submitScoreIsValid(this.id).toPromise();
  if (star.isValid === true) {
    await this.judgeService.write(this.id, {score: this.currentScore}).toPromise();
    this.status = true;
  } else {
    this.status = false;
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
} finally {
  $timeout(() => this.isLoading = false, 3000);
}
}`